# hammer.js scroll not working with pinchin and pinchout events

Tags: pinch, hammer.js

I am using hammer.js to catch pinchin and pinchout events and change font size of the page. So, I have written the following code:

```
        var touch_area = document.getElementById('touch-area');
        var hammertime = Hammer(touch_area).on("pinchin pinchout", function (ev) {
            //alert(ev.type);
            if(ev.type=="pinchin")
                decreaseFontSize();
            else
                increaseFontSize();

        });
```

It works but it disables the vertical scroll. How can I solve it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ashish Maradiya's works fine to me but only on android.

After a lot of research I achieved to do it in android and iphone using only this code:

```
    var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, {
        touchAction: 'manipulation'
    });
    mc.add([new Hammer.Pinch()]);

    mc.on("pinchin", function (ev) {
        //code
    });
    mc.on("pinchout", function (ev) {
        //code
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

apply css property to your (#touch-area) div

```css
#touch-area{
touch-action: pan-x pan-y !important;
}
```

hammer.js pinch, pincin, pinchout event always add touch-action:none property than our scroling property not working

Answer (score -1):

try adding this css:

```
body {overflow-y:scroll;}
```

if later, you want both vertical and horizontal scrollbars enabled, use this

```
body{ overflow: scroll; }
```